# Google Sheet Api get function returning undefined value in nodejs

Tags: google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

```
function changeData(auth,sheetId) {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: sheetId,
    range: 'Sheet1!D6', 
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {
      values: [ ["abc"] ]
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    } else {
        console.log("Appended");
    }
  });
}
```

I can get the above function to work and it changes the value just fine but the below function doesnt return value and says 0 rows retrieved. what am i doing wrong?

```
function read(auth,sheet_id)
    {
      var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: sheet_id,
        range: 'Sheet1!D6'
      }, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          // Handle error
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
          console.log('%d rows retrieved.', numRows);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using googleapis after the version of v26.0.1 (now it's 32.0.0.), in your script, you can retrieve the data by `result.data`. So how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
```

#### To :

```
var numRows = result.data.values ? result.data.values.length : 0;
```

Comment: @Mushfiq please engage in the expected practice of accepting answers that solve your issues. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329  While it is never a requirement to award the green tick to the most helpful answer, it does help future researchers to identify good answers and it is a way to reward the volunteers who help you.  Please award green ticks to the best answer that solves your issue on ALL of your questions.  If any of your questions are still unresolved, please edit/improve them and perhaps leave a comment to anyone who took interest on the page.

Comment: It's took me a lot of times to find the answer, there is no clue on any google documents or guide, they should update it! Anyway, thanks for the answer!