# Google Sheets API values.append Returning incorrect response

Tags: google-sheets-api

Trying to write a Firebase cloud function that appends user information to a spreadsheet. I want the values of the range updated so I can use it if the user changes their mind to update the spreadsheet.

```
    async function writeToSpreadSheet(firstName: string, lastName: string, response: string, spreadSheetId: string, date:string, userEmail:string): Promise<Schema$AppendValuesResponse> {
  await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: jwtClient,
    spreadsheetId: spreadSheetId,
    range: 'Sheet1!A1:C3',  // update this range of cells
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    requestBody: {"values": [[firstName, lastName,userEmail, response, date]]},
  }, (err, res) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res);
    return;
  });
}
```

For some reason I am getting a huge response like:

```
     { status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: 
       { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
         vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
         ...
}
```

Instead of a nice:

```
  {
  "spreadsheetId": "{spreadsheetId}",
  "tableRange": "Sheet1!A1:C18",
}
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: This worked thanks. In truth, I am really looking for a way to update specific values that have been appended. Dont want to use the range because this might change if someone edits the spreadsheet. How might you suggest searching for a specific value in a table then updating the row?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About ``How might you suggest searching for a specific value in a table then updating the row?``, it seems that it is the different question. So can you post it as new question? At that time, please include the detail information. It will help users think of about your issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the properties of only `spreadsheetId` and `tableRange` as the response.
- You are using googleapis of Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  auth: jwtClient,
  spreadsheetId: spreadSheetId,
  range: 'Sheet1!A1:C3',  // update this range of cells
  valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  requestBody: {"values": [[firstName, lastName,userEmail, response, date]]},
  fields: "spreadsheetId,tableRange",  // Added
}, (err, res) => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res.data);  // Modified
  return;
});
```

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [About response from API using googleapis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740728/7108653)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.